# readfile() from database longblob

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a legacy system that stores files in the DB as `LONGBLOB`

What I am trying to achieve is that the user can visit a URL and download a specific file. Now on the part where I try to read the file, I believe I am missing something. PHP is giving me `readfile() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given [] []`

So I can deduce that I cannot directly feed the `LONGBLOB` into the `readfile()` method. Is there another way of piping the file out to the user?

Here is the code I am trying to use at the moment:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM DOC_Documents WHERE DOC_ID = ?');
$stmt->execute([$docID]);
$document = $stmt->fetch();

$filename = str_replace(' ', '', $document['DOC_Name']);
$filename .= '.';
$filename .= $document['DOC_Extension'];

header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: " . $document["DOC_Type"]);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
readfile(trim($document['DOC_File']));
```

Comment: `readfile` reads file content from the file system, and therefor wants a file system path as parameter - using it with a blob makes no sense to begin with. Just echo the blob contents directly …

Comment: @misorude - Thanks the echo works. Can't believe I didn't think of that.